# Woocommerce - show reviews from a different product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, review

I have a main product in our WooCommerce store where all the reviews are, let's say it is product id 123. There are other products in our store on which I'd like the review tab to show the reviews from product id 123 instead of their own reviews. These other products have ids 124, 125, and 126.

What do I need to override or hook into so that I can show product reviews for 123 on product pages 124, 125, and 126?

Comment: Hi David, I'm looking for the same solution. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up using a plugin that would show reviews for multiple products.

Comment: Can you please tell me the plugin's name?

Comment: This is the plug I'm using "SIP Reviews Shortcode for WooCommerce." It looks like I ended up having all the reviews for the entire product line under one ID and then displayed those reviews on all the pages using this plugin. That way all the reviews could be managed and displayed from one ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin to do this. 
https://www.appjetty.com/woocommerce-copy-or-move-reviews.htm